# What is wrong with my Python syntax: I am trying to use multiple quotation marks plus variables in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, quotations

I am trying to use Python to write to a file. However, the code has multiple `"` in it plus calls a variable. I simply cannot manage the syntax.

The code should result in:

```
{
"Name of site": "https://.google.com",
```

Where the website is a variable not a string.

The code attempt is below. It never resolves the variable and just displays it as a string called `host_name`. I have attempted to add backslashes and quotations (various types of single and double) but whatever I try does not work.

```
with open ("new_file.txt", "a") as f:
           f.write ("{ \n")
           
           f.write("\"Name of site\": \"https://" + host_name + ", \n")
```

The new_file.txt shows:

```
"Name of site":  "https:// + host_name + "\," + "
```

I have no idea where the `"\,"` comes from.

Comment: Why not just make a dictionary and then handle it as json?

Comment: you can try this: `f.write(f'"Name of site": "https://{host_name}",\n')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use f strings, and take advantage of the fact that both `''` and `""` create string literals.

```py
>>> host_name = example.com
>>> output = "{\n"+ f'"Name of site": "https://{host_name}",' + "\n"
>>> print(output)
{
"Name of site": "https://example.com",
```

Note that in that example you have to *also* concatenate strings in order to avoid the fact that f-strings don't allow either braces or backslashes; however, there is even a way around that.

```py
newline = '\n'
l_curly = "{"
output = f'{l_curly}{newline}"Name of site": "https://{host_name}", {newline}'
```

So that's how you'd build the string directly. But it does also seem more likely that what you really want to is to construct a dictionary, then write that dictionary out using JSON.

```py
>>> import json
>>> host_name = 'example.com'
>>> data = {"Name of site": f"https://{host_name}"}
>>> output = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
>>> print(output)
{
    "Name of site": "https://example.com"
}
```

Comment: No need to define `curly` and `newline`. You can add the newline as `\n` and escape the `{` with another `{`. This will lead to: `output = f'{{\n"Name of site": "https://{host_name}", \n'`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice: I ended up with `f.write(f" \"Title\": \"https://" + website_name + "\", \n")` I didn't realise one could use f strings with the write function.